# How can I extract exactly 2 keys and values from several objects in an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json-file

```
artist:[
{artist: "Henry", Year :"XYZ", album: "ABC", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "Lisa", Year :"1998", album: "All the time", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "David", Year :"2001", album: "Lets go", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "James", Year :"1997", album: "Memories", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "Julia", Year :"2002", album: "Technology", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "Bob", Year :"1995", album: "Chill 5", image: "image.jpg"}
{artist: "Frank", Year :"1996", album: "DeadRat", image: "image.jpg"}
]
```

I  want to extract artist, album and image and dynamically put it on the website. How can i do that?

Comment: Which artists, albums, and images? Also, what did *you* try?

Comment: In the title you've said 2 keys but in the description you've mentioned 3 (`artist`, `album` and `image`). In any case, you can do this kind of thing using [`.map(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```js
const artist=[
{artist: "Henry", Year :"XYZ", album: "ABC", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "Lisa", Year :"1998", album: "All the time", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "David", Year :"2001", album: "Lets go", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "James", Year :"1997", album: "Memories", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "Julia", Year :"2002", album: "Technology", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "Bob", Year :"1995", album: "Chill 5", image: "image.jpg"},
{artist: "Frank", Year :"1996", album: "DeadRat", image: "image.jpg"}
]
var arr = artist.map(x=>{return {artist:x.artist,album:x.album,image:x.image}})
console.log(arr)
```

})

in order to show your data on the React application, you can follow [this Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-water-gr4px?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
function App() {
  const artist = [
    { artist: "Henry", Year: "XYZ", album: "ABC", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "Lisa", Year: "1998", album: "All the time", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "David", Year: "2001", album: "Lets go", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "James", Year: "1997", album: "Memories", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "Julia", Year: "2002", album: "Technology", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "Bob", Year: "1995", album: "Chill 5", image: "image.jpg" },
    { artist: "Frank", Year: "1996", album: "DeadRat", image: "image.jpg" }
  ];
  var arr = artist.map(x => {
    return { artist: x.artist, album: x.album, image: x.image };
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map(x => {
        return (
          <div>
            {x.album} : {x.artist}
            <img alt="" src={x.src} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```